# vim-go with golangci-lint and revive (replacing deprecated go-lint): Confused about correct config

Tags: go, vim, lint, golint, vim-go

I am having a really hard time getting vim-go to play well with golanci-lint.

`golint`, which was a default linter for go, has been deprecated. Most users now suggest to use `revive`.

While the default config of `vim-go` with `golint` was working, but printing a deprecated message on the status line, if I put `revive` instead, I only get

```
vim-go: [golangci-lint] FAIL
```

Ubuntu 20.04, with `8.1.2269-1ubuntu5`
vim-go: `v1.25`

.vimrc:

```
  let g:go_metalinter_enabled = []

  let g:go_metalinter_command = 'golangci-lint'
  let g:go_metalinter_autosave = 1
  let g:go_metalinter_autosave_enabled = ['vet','revive','errcheck','staticcheck','unused','varcheck']
```

Comment: Actually - I *think* what is going on is that if there's no linting issue, then it prints "SUCCESS", but if the linting fails, instead of the list, I just get `vim-go: [golangci-lint] FAIL`

Comment: I believe what the actual problem was is that I had conflictive settings with `coc.nvim`.

Comment: So ahm, did you solve this and how?

Comment: I think it's working now as it is above, maybe I was having other interfering issues @Eksapsy

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yeah I guess sometimes vim plugin configurations get to result in a bit weird situations.

Comment: I have the same problem!